# Checking a string is one of the following

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to write a script where at the beginning it only runs if the user is one of the following:  Peter, Paul, Simon:

I do:

```
if [[ "$(whoami)" != peter && "$(whoami)" != paul && "$(whoami)" != simon]]; then
    echo -e "\nPlease run this script as someone who is allowed" >&amp;2
    exit 1
fi
```

I get:

```
syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `;'
```

Any tips?  Or better still, a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[konsolebox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18623246/2698019) is correct about space character before `]]`.

But if you don't want to mess with extended globs you can use regexp:

```
if [[ $(whoami) =~ ^(peter|paul|simon)$ ]]; then
```

Or even

```
if [[ $USER =~ ^(peter|paul|simon)$ ]]; then
```

Comment: If `(( BASH_VERSINFO < 4 ))`, store it on a variable first: `if R='^(peter|paul|simon)$'; [[ $(whoami) =~ $R ]]; then`.

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to add a space at the end:

```
... != simon ]]
```

Also if you could consider using extended globs, you could have it simpler like this:

```
shopt -s extglob
if [[ $(whoami) != @(peter|paul|simon) ]]; then
```

And a little old-fashioned but POSIX compatible way:

```
case $(whoami) in
peter|paul|simon)
    ;;
*)
    echo -e "\nPlease run this script as someone who is allowed" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Somewhat surprisingly, you don't need quotes around the selector in `case`.

Comment: +1 The `case` statement is the way to go if you need portability. The call to `shopt` is only necessary prior to 4.1, when it became the default setting for globs inside `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: @tripleee I got used to quoting it and I don't know if it's always not reinterpreted in other shells like with word splitting and pathname expansion. I started doing it when I started making scripts that were intended to be compatible with System V sh, and I can't remember if there was a reason why it should be quoted. I wish someone could verify that it's not needed.

Comment: From the sh standard for `case`: "The conditional construct case shall execute the compound-list corresponding to the first one of several patterns (see Pattern Matching Notation) that is matched by the string resulting from the tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal of the given word."  Word-splitting is not performed, so quotes are not necessary.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks for the info. I guess I'll consider it. I made an update.